# Nested HTTP Error on get request with Node.js

Tags: node.js, http

I'm having a problem, and I feel out of my depth when it comes to troubleshooting these problems.

One, my understanding of Node is very new/immature, and two my understanding of http isn't the strongest.

So here it goes out to the community for some hopeful help.

I've vetted my code, by first abstracting it's intent by using statically typed arrays of objects, and run it browser side to ensure all was working as expected (lacking the http.get request).

I've moved the same code over to the Node server side and have run it successfully with the same abstract data-set that I used locally, and all worked fine (Primary PORT 3030 Instance).

I then proceeded to introduce a http.get which is a little more complicated in more than one way.

**Explanation**:

Everything that I am doing is happening on my local machine for testing/non-production status development.

[image: MyServerSetup]

This being the case, I am ultimately performing an http.get request from my local machine on port 3030 and calling out to another instance of node (running on a separate instance of cmd.exe) listening on port 3000.

I've tested 3000 with the browser on its own, and it is working as expected:

I fire up chrome, goto http://:3000/bend/1, and it returns what I have set it up for (it runs a SQL select statement on the last value provided in the URL, and returns a JSON.stringify(obj) back to the browser -- See Image Below).

[image: Proof_Of_3000_Working]

Then I point my browser to http://:3030 and get:

```
Server Started on Port 3030...
TypeError: listener must be a function
    at TypeError (native)
    at ClientRequest.once (events.js:190:11)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:93:10)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
    at Object.exports.get (http.js:53:21)
    at getBendAndTypeByBend (<<MyPort3030Root>>\program.js:26:9)
    at p_processBends (<<MyPort3030Root>>\program.js:58:14)
    at doAll (<<MyPort3030Root>>\program.js:74:3)
    at <<MyPort3030Root>>\program.js:82:2
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (<<MyPort3030Root>>\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

I will be glad to show the code, but I'm not sure which section is really needed to troubleshoot the issue, as when there is not an HTTP.GET request, then each of these run fine in their own right.

I just don't know which way is which right now, and I'm hoping that someone here can help me understand where to begin understanding the problem, but ultimately how to solve it as well.

I know that this may be asking a lot, but I really feel stuck on this one because things seem to be working until I hook them together.

---

**Here is the suspect code snippets being called from PORT : 3030**

```
http = require('http');
fs = require('fs');
async = require('async');
q = require('q');
express = require('express');

app = express();

bends = [
    {"bend" : "1", "type" : ""},
    {"bend" : "2", "type" : ""},
    {"bend" : "7", "type" : ""},
    {"bend" : "14", "type" : ""},
    {"bend" : "33", "type" : ""},
    {"bend" : "48", "type" : ""},
    {"bend" : "73", "type" : ""},
    {"bend" : "82", "type" : ""}
];

function getBendAndTypeByBend(bendStr) {
  result = {"bend" : "", "type" : "", "status" : "false"};
  for (var i=0;i<bends.length;i++) {
      http.get('http://localhost:3000/bend/'+bendStr, 'utf-8', function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.on('end', function(err, res1) {
            result.bend = bendStr;
            result.type = JSON.parse(res).row;
            if(i == bends.length-1) {
                result.status = "true";
                return result;
            } else {
                result.status = "false";
            }
        })
      });*/
  }
}

function p_initTables() {
  bt1 = bends.slice();//(b)end(t)able1
  return bt1;
}

function p_processBends(btArr) {
    localbt = btArr.slice();
    //console.log(localbt);
    newbt = [];
    for(var i=0;i<localbt.length;i++){
        newbt.push(
            {
                "bend" : localbt[i].bend,
                "type" : getBendAndTypeByBend(localbt[i].bend).type
            }
        );
    }
    return newbt;
}

function p_renderBendTableToUser(bt) {
    for(var i=0;i<bt.length;i++) {
        console.log("BEND: "+bt[i].bend + " | TYPE: "+bt[i].type+"\n");
    }
    return console.log("\ndone");
}

function doAll() { 
    p_renderBendTableToUser(
        p_processBends(
            p_initTables()
        )
    );
    return 1;
}

app.get('/', function() {
    doAll();
});

app.listen(3030, function(err, res){
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log('Server Started on Port 3030...');
});

app.listen(3030, function(err, res){
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log('Server Started on Port 3030...');
});
```

---

**Here is the code being called run @ PORT : 3000**

```
var express = require('express');
var sql = require('sqlite3');

app = express();

app.get('/bend/:id', function(req, res){
    var db = new sql.Database('<mySQLite3Path>/rebarFabTypes.db');
    db.get("SELECT bend, type FROM fabtype WHERE bend = '"+req.params.id+"'", function(err, row) {
        if (typeof row !== 'undefined') {
            console.log(row.type);
            res.end(JSON.stringify({"row" : row.type}));
        } else {
            res.end(JSON.stringify({"row" : "UNKNOWN"}));
        }
    });
    db.close();
});

app.listen(3000, function(err, resp){
    console.log('Server Started on Port 3000...');
});
```

Comment: reading this makes me feel like I'm back in school again..narrow it down.. and post some code from the script in which the error occurs.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix OK, I'll post both sides just so you can see what is happening.

Comment: well..there are many wrong things going on with both scripts if you want to make an http get request from  one server to another try `request` module it will make things easier. Also try reading some express tutorials and always use the documentation. NodeJS and http module are not "immature" or "weak".

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix I believe that you have misunderstood me. I said my understanding/knowledge of these are immature/week, not their individual capabilities. As far as looking at docs on the web, that also is why I am here. I'm having a hard time putting them into play to my situation. As for my appended code snippets, I was trying to get concise to where the issue was happening, but in retrospect those snippets make no sense as they are, so I will repost my full code sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem might be in this line.

```
http.get('http://localhost:3000/bend/'+bendStr, 'utf-8', function(err, res) {
```

Going by the documentation - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback,   the second parameter to http.get should be a function.  In your case it is the third parameter (which is what node seems to be complaining about in the stack trace)

Try dropping the second parameter **utf-8** and you should be able to get past that error.

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't seeing it. Most likely because I'm mixing approaches.